# Show images from facebook using PHP and graph api photos

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, photos

I am trying to show my thumbnails of photos from my facebook fan page. I have studied the facebook dev and graph api. Now I am trying to using php to automate the process and show the images on my photo page.

```
$facebook_album = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/10150101465621686/photos");
```

which returns the following data with the image data repeating for each image (see below):

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "10150101465701686",
         "from": {
            "name": "Lingua Language Academy",
            "category": "Organization",
            "id": "55206251685"
         },
         "picture": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/185883_10150101465701686_55206251685_6497497_7724100_s.jpg",
         "source": "http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/185883_10150101465701686_55206251685_6497497_7724100_n.jpg",
         "height": 540,
         "width": 720,
         "images": [
            {
               "height": 540,
               "width": 720,
               "source": "http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/185883_10150101465701686_55206251685_6497497_7724100_n.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 135,
               "width": 180,
               "source": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/185883_10150101465701686_55206251685_6497497_7724100_a.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 97,
               "width": 130,
               "source": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/185883_10150101465701686_55206251685_6497497_7724100_s.jpg"
            },
            {
               "height": 56,
               "width": 75,
               "source": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/185883_10150101465701686_55206251685_6497497_7724100_t.jpg"
            }
         ],
         "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=6497497&id=55206251685",
         "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yz/r/StEh3RhPvjk.gif",
         "created_time": "2011-02-22T02:41:02+0000",
         "position": 1,
         "updated_time": "2011-02-22T02:41:04+0000"
      },
```

My questions is... Is there an easy way to put the following info in an array that will be easy to loop through?

Something like so that it loops through the data and puts the value of picture in the image src.

```
foreach( $facebook_album as $key => $value){
    echo "<img src='picture'/><br />";
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try json_decode of the json data ?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

$dataArr = json_decode($dataStr,true);

$imageArr = $dataArr["images"];

Comment: This is the function I am going to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me

```
$dataArr = json_decode($facebook_album,true);
foreach($dataArr['data'] as $d){    
    echo "<img src=\"".$d['source']."\"><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code (php sdk)

```
if($user_id){
            // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
            // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
            try{
                $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
                $photos = $facebook->api("/me/photos");

......
...
..
}
```

Start showing photos one by one

```
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo){
                    echo "<p><img src='";
                    echo $photo['images'][0]['source'];
                    echo "'/></p>";
                }
```